# Segmentation of user who have visited a certain page during a time period

Tags: google-analytics, marketing, users, website-promotion

At the moment I am doing some analysis about user behaviour and I am particularly interest in those user that have the following behaviour:

- Visitor visited a promotion page e.g. "promotion" during week 1
- How many of the above visitor above visit the promotion page again? How many of the above visitor above visit the site but NOT the promotion again? How much of them get converted?

I try to setup a segment like the following:
[image]

May I know if the above means the following?

> Visitor visited the promotion page between 26 Aug 2018 and 1 Sep 2018 but they come back to the site not visiting promotion page at all between 2 Sep 2018 and 8 Sep 2018

I am also thinking about setting a dedicated view for the promotion page but I was wondering if that is overkill.

Comment: What you are looking for is called [cohort analysis](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6158745?hl=en).  I don't think segments is the proper way to solve that problem.   GA has other built in features for it.

Comment: Thanks for the information!

In this case, how can I use cohort analysis to only see the behaviour of the user that have visited the promotion on week 1?

Comment: I believe the problem here is that this is not set into sequence. Now you have defined two user' groups. The results will show all results fitting one of these two conditions. If you would use the sequences option you can indeed set that these conditions should follow each other. .

Answer (score 1):

I think segments **are** the way to get at what you want; segments are the only way I know to connect specific user behavior across sessions (cohort analysis may get there, but it currently cannot scope in to anything other than new visitors in a given time period).

Your segment is close to what you need but not quite there. The logic you have will pick out users who visited the promotion page during the first week, and then visited a non-promotion page during the second week - but that second session could also include the promotion page; it just can't include **only** the promotion page.

One change to your segment definition will find people who visited the promotion page in both weeks: put "contains" in the second filter instead of "does not contain":

```
Filter Users Include 
- Session Date between Aug 26 and Sep 1, 2018
and
- Page contains promotion

Filter Users Include
- Session Date between Sep 2 and Sep 8, 2018
and
- Page contains promotion
```

[image: Screenshot of segment definition to capture users who visited the promotion page in two consecutive weeks]

To get at the people who came back but did not re-visit the promotion page, you must first change your week 2 filter above to "Exclude". That will eliminate people who re-visited the promotion page, but it will allow people who never came back at all. This segment needs a third filter to make sure people came back:

```
Filter Users Include
- Session Date between Sep 2 and Sep 8, 2018
```

[image: Screenshot of segment definition to capture users who visited the promotion page in one week, and returned without visiting the promotion page the following week]

I cannot think of a way to set up a dedicated View that would help with this - I think applying these segments to your main View will be the best way to get at these users' activity.